# Mutually nonisomorphic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

[image]

I know this has something to do with Sylow's theorems but I don't really understand how they apply. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $A\times B$ is abelian $\iff $ both $A$ and $B$ are abelian

Comment: The orders of their centres are all different.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $   ~~~\mathbb{Z_{30}}$ is abelian while $D_{15}$ is non-abelian. In general $D_n$ is non-abelian for $n\geq3$, can you see from this why others are not isomorphic?

Comment: So there can't be an isomorphism from an abelian group to a non abelian group?

Comment: If there exists an isomorphism between any two algebraic structures then the nature of the two structures are same, meaning you prove some result on one, it remains valid for the other also. So if one is abelian and other is not then commutative property of one will not satisfied by the elements of the other, so it contradicts.